# Get key/value mapping of cache only cache hits from IRedisClient

Tags: c#, caching, redis, servicestack.redis

I am using v3 of the Redis client provided by ServiceStack. I'm implementing the "decorator pattern" and have a class that wraps the caching logic around my repository so that if there are cache misses, I can look to the repository for the data. The problem is that there are certain cases where I would like to add `null` to the cache so that there is an entry, but just no value. This would mean that I would **not** go to the database for that value.

What I need to know is if there is any way to get a mapping of key/value for **only** cache hits for the `IRedisClient` interface.

There are multiple methods of retrieving the values from the cache using this interface. First, I've tried the `GetAll<T>` method. This returns items from the cache and a default value for `T` if it doesn't exist. This doesn't help me because it makes it seem like there I've added a `null` entry for a given key.

I then tried `GetValues` but that only returns the values it found, and not the associated key.

Finally, I tried `GetValuesMap<T>` but this seems to act exactly like `GetAll<T>`.

Does anyone know a way to get a mapping of only the cache hits?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IRedisClient has a method called **ContainsKey(string key)** you could check this before you attempt a Get.

If ContainsKey returns true, you know that if you get back a null value, that you added it yourself.

Comment: Using this method, I lose the power of hitting the cache once and checking for many entries.